# How to extract element from a webpage with special class name?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a txt file filed with multiple urls, each url is an article with text and their corresponding SDG (example of one article [1](http://sdg.iisd.org/news/tools-support-policy-makers-efforts-to-prioritize-multiple-goals/))

The text parts of an article are in balises 'div.text.-normal.content' and then in 'p'
And the SDGs are in 'div.tax-section.text.-normal.small' and then in 'span'

To extract them I use the following lines of code :

```
data = []

with open('urls_news.txt', 'r') as inf:
    for row in inf:
        url = row.strip()
        response = requests.get(url, headers={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
            
        if response.ok:
            try:
                soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"html.parser")
                text = soup.select_one('div.text-normal').get_text(strip=True)
                topic = soup.select_one('div.tax-section').get_text(strip=True)

                data.append(
                    {
                    'text':text,
                    'topic': topic,
                    }
                )
                
                pd.DataFrame(data).to_excel('text_2.xlsx', index = False, header=True)

            except AttributeError:
                print (" ")

    time.sleep(3)
```

But I have no result, I've previously used this code to extract same type of information from an other website with clearer class name. I'va also tried to enter "div.text.-normal.content" and "div.tax-section.text.-normal.small" but same result.

I think that the classes i'm calling in this exemple are wrong. I would like to know what i've missed in theses classes names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select the text you can go with:

```
soup.select_one('div.text.-normal.content').get_text(strip=True)
```

Think there is something wrong with the names of the classes, just chain them with a `.` for every whitespace between them.

or:

```
soup.select_one('div.c-single-content').get_text(strip=True)
```

To get the topics as mentioned you can go with:

```
'^^'.join([topic.get_text(strip=True) for topic in soup.select_one('div.tax-section.text.-normal.small').select('a')])
```

Comment: The goal is to obtain at the end a xlsx file with a column text and topics (each line represente one article) for the page I gave in exemple I would like, for the column text to obtain the text starting by "The SDGs provide a framework for addressing multiple priorities...." to "externalities that result from infrastructure development. " and in topic column "9. industry, innovation..." and "17. partnership..."

Comment: I used your fisrt line suggestion for text and it is ok, then I 've tried soup.select_one('div.tax-section.text.-normal.small').get_text(strip=True) for topics and all is ok. Thanks for your help